# How to expose a Mongoose / MongoDB query as an Express route

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I would like to create an express route for creating a RESTful url passing its query parameters to the Mongoose query. Something like this (not working) code mapping the limit and sort parameters from the url and otherwise using defaults. The url would be:

myhost/processes?limit=20&sort=-modified

```
exports.find = function(req, res) {

var options = {
    limit : 100,
    sort: '-created'
};

_(options).extend(req.query);

Process.find(options, function(err, process) {
    res.send(process);
});

}
```

I only know how to pass the query parameters to individual methods like find() and sort() that no way to map this in a more automatic fashion. Or is what I'm trying to do a bad idea in terms of RESTful api? I'm using Mongoose but but I would be interested in a solution using the native driver if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the underscore library's `extend` you can do it like this:

```js
exports.find = function(req, res) {

  var options = {
    limit : 100,
    sort: {created: -1}
  };
  _.extend(options, req.query);

  Process.find({}, null, options, function(err, process) {
    res.send(process);
  });
}
```

The `options` parameter will be passed into the [`Query#setOptions`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions) method, and many of the options are passed through directly to the node.js native driver, so for things like `sort` see the native [`find` docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find).  As you can see, the format of `sort` isn't conducive to being provided in a URL parameter.

It's more secure to only expose support for specific options and then individually pull those in from `req.query` rather than using `extend`, but either way can work.

Comment: Really? I tried it and those options don't seem to have any influence on the query. I tried to find documentation on this but can't find it either. Can you point me to it?

Comment: @0x80 It does work, but you have to use the right format for the options data which is typically the native format, not the mongoose form.  See updated answer.